# Basic transfer text to structure program in C. Why do I keep getting weird output?

Tags: c, file, pointers, structure

Here is my program, you can just ignore the main part:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int assignments[5];
    int labs[5];
    int midterm;
    int finalM;
}myclass;

myclass gng1105[10];
void update();
void printList();
void addStudent();
int main(){
    int option;
    update();
    while(option!= 3){
    printf("Please enter the option number:\n1.View the information for a specific    student\n2.add a student number\n3.Exist\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    if(option == 1){
        printList();
    }
    else if (option == 2){
    addStudent();
    }
    else if (option == 3){
        printf("system closed");
        break;
    }
    else{
         printf("invalid input");
    }

   printf("******************************************************************************\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }

void update(){
     FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("myclass.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Error opening file\n");
     else{
      while(!feof(fp)){
      fscanf(fp,"%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", gng1105[i].firstname, 
                                                gng1105[i].lastname,
                                                &gng1105[i].assignments[0],
                                                &gng1105[i].assignments[1],
                                                &gng1105[i].assignments[2],
                                                &gng1105[i].assignments[3],
                                                &gng1105[i].assignments[4],
                                                &gng1105[i].labs[0],
                                                &gng1105[i].labs[1],
                                                &gng1105[i].labs[2],
                                                &gng1105[i].labs[3],
                                                &gng1105[i].labs[4],
                                                &gng1105[i].midterm,
                                                &gng1105[i].finalM);
      i++;

      }
    }
    fclose(fp);

}

void printList(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i <10 ; i++){
        printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", gng1105[i].firstname,
                                                            gng1105[i].lastname,
                                                            gng1105[i].assignments[0],
                                                            gng1105[i].assignments[1],
                                                            gng1105[i].assignments[2],
                                                            gng1105[i].assignments[3],
                                                            gng1105[i].assignments[4],
                                                            gng1105[i].labs[0],
                                                            gng1105[i].labs[1],
                                                            gng1105[i].labs[2],
                                                            gng1105[i].labs[3],
                                                            gng1105[i].labs[4],
                                                            gng1105[i].midterm,
                                                            gng1105[i].finalM);
    }

}


void   addStudent(){
}
```

Here is what txt file looks like:

```
Marcus Hill 100001 64 54 68 71 60 55 43 30 70 0 70 81 

Brian Wyllie 100002 90 96 89 91 93 90 85 89 95 100 100 90

Soren Bjerg 100003 70 84 74 75 90 81 70 0 77 82 73 80

Jason Tran 100004 53 0 56 50 0 69 30 50 51 67 70 65 

Alex Chu 100004 85 85 83 80 65 94 89 79 89 69 50 90
```

Here is the output, it looks so weird, even the error looks inconsistent(couldn't post image sorry):

> Marcus Hill 100001 64 54 68 71 60 55 43 30 70 0 **7081** brian 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0Willie 10002 90 96 89 91 93 90 85 95 100 100 90soren Bjerg 1000003 70 84 74 75 90 81 70 0 77 82 **7380** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

(I highlighted error, except those damn zeros)

I'd be really appreciate if anyone would help me!

Comment: The first thing you should probably do is add `\n` to the end of your `printf()` format string, so that your output is broken up into one line per record. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot a `studentId` field in your `struct`.  You're assigning the student ID number (e.g. 100001) to `gng1105[i].assignments[0]`.

Your `struct` should be defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int studentId; // <<<------ This is missing
    int assignments[5];
    int labs[5];
    int midterm;
    int finalM;
} myclass;
```

You need an extra format specifier and variable here:

```
fscanf(fp,"%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%", gng1105[i].firstname, 
                                           gng1105[i].lastname,
                                           &gng1105[i].studentId, // <<<--- This is missing
                                           &gng1105[i].assignments[0],
                                           &gng1105[i].assignments[1],
                                           &gng1105[i].assignments[2],
                                           &gng1105[i].assignments[3],
                                           &gng1105[i].assignments[4],
                                           &gng1105[i].labs[0],
                                           &gng1105[i].labs[1],
                                           &gng1105[i].labs[2],
                                           &gng1105[i].labs[3],
                                           &gng1105[i].labs[4],
                                           &gng1105[i].midterm,
                                           &gng1105[i].finalM);
```

Don't forget this:

```
printf("%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", gng1105[i].firstname,
                                                       gng1105[i].lastname,
                                                       gng1105[I].studentId, // <<<--- Missing
                                                       gng1105[i].assignments[0],
                                                       gng1105[i].assignments[1],
                                                       gng1105[i].assignments[2],
                                                       gng1105[i].assignments[3],
                                                       gng1105[i].assignments[4],
                                                       gng1105[i].labs[0],
                                                       gng1105[i].labs[1],
                                                       gng1105[i].labs[2],
                                                       gng1105[i].labs[3],
                                                       gng1105[i].labs[4],
                                                       gng1105[i].midterm,
                                                       gng1105[i].finalM);
```

Don't forget `fscanf` and `printf` both need an extra `%d`.

Comment: @user3064115 Can you post the new output?

Comment: It was my mistake, fine now.... thank you so much! I'm feeling very dumb right now... spent one hour on this stupid small mistake.

Comment: @user3064115 Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.  Glad I could help.